# How to hold filter parameters. Pagination

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, pagination

I have some problem with search filter and pagination. Filter works good, but i can't say the same about pagination.

I have a table with users. I can show all users or by filter(by name, by email). When i'm using filter and trying to go to second page, it return all users without filtration. I understand why it happens, because has no filter parameters. Help me find solution. How can i hold selected filters? Something with sessions?
Here my code.

My **Controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin")
public class AdminController {

@Autowired
UserService userService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/edit-user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView editUsers(@RequestParam(value = "page", defaultValue = "0") Integer page,
                              @RequestParam(value = "pattern", required = false) String pattern,
                              @RequestParam(value = "category", required = false) String category) {
    ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("edit-user");
    if(pattern == null){
        Page<User> userList = userService.findAll(page);
        view.addObject("userList", userList.getContent()).addObject("maxPage", userList.getTotalPages());
    }else if(category.equals("username")){
        Page<User> userList = userService.findByUsernameContaining(pattern, page);
        view.addObject("userList", userList.getContent()).addObject("maxPage", userList.getTotalPages());
    }else {
        Page<User> userList = userService.findByEmailContaining(pattern, page);
        view.addObject("userList", userList.getContent()).addObject("maxPage", userList.getTotalPages());
    }
    return view;
}
}
```

My part of **JSP**

```html
<div class="row top-buffer">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <form class="form-inline text-center" role="form" method="get" action="/admin/edit-user?pattern=pattern?category=category">
                    <fieldset>
                        <!-- Search Name -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="item-name">Product Name</label>
                            <input id="item-name" name="pattern" placeholder="..." class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <!-- Search Category -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="item-category">Product Category</label>
                            <select id="item-category" name="category" class="form-control">
                                <option value="username" selected>By username</option>
                                <option value="email">By email</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Search Action -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row top-buffer">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Username</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Password</th>
                    </thead>
                    <c:forEach var="user" items="${userList}">
                        <tr>
                            <td>${user.id}</td>
                            <td>${user.username}</td>
                            <td>${user.email}</td>
                            <td>${user.password}</td>
                            <td>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm editButton" data-toggle="modal"
                                        data-target="#myModal" data-id="${user.id}">Edit
                                </button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 pull-right">
                <ul class="pagination">
                    <c:forEach begin="0" end="${maxPage - 1}" var="i">
                        <li><a href="/admin/edit-user?page=${i}">${i+1}</a></li>
                    </c:forEach>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Ohhh, and one more question. When i'm trying to make @Requestparam like Map<String, String>, map is always null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, putting filter information in session should be OK. You can create a **Filter** enum that has e.g. **name**, **email** fields. Store/update a **Filter** instance in session every time user wants to filter something.

You can attach your **filters** to your link(page number in your case) as a query string like so:
`<a href="/admin/edit-user?page=${i}&filterby=${filter}">${i+1}</a>`

In your controller, you need to get the filter information and handle it accordingly (get the value of param **filterby**, which is **name** or **email**). If the **filterby** param has no value, then no filter is chosen.